# alignat not aligning properly with two &

Tags: align, alignment, alignat

[image]

Why is alignat not aligning as expected here? (The lines indicate how I expect the expressions to lign up)

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
     &\bigg[\overline X - z_\frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}};  \quad 
    &&
    &\overline X + z_\frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
    \\[1em]
    &\bigg[\overline X - 0.4; 
    &&
    &\overline X + 0.4 
\end{alignat*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only 2 alignment points. Below the top image covers your original layout while the bottom image shows the adjusted layout (with one less `&`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &\biggl[\overline{X} - z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}; \quad 
  &&
  &\overline{X} + z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
  \\[1em]
  &\biggl[\overline{X} - 0.4; 
  &&
  &\overline{X} + 0.4 
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\biggl[\overline{X} - z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}; \quad 
  &&
  \overline{X} + z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
  \\[1em]
  &\biggl[\overline{X} - 0.4; 
  &&
  \overline{X} + 0.4 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```